# Laravel how to get nested object value in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-8

I have Laravel 8 I am using Laravel Spatie package for roles and permissions.

I am getting all admin users with roles and sending that to vuejs e.g

```
$users = Admin::orderBy('id','DESC')->with('roles')->get();
```

In Vue Component i have

```
<tr v-for="(user,index) in users" :key="users.id">
```

I am trying to display all users in a table with their name and their role. i am able to get name but not role name.

I want to access role name inside roles object.

Thank You

Comment: its laravel collection and for each item in collection it has another collection of roles that contains role information in it.

Answer (score 0):

you can access a collection of roles in vue.js as `user.roles` array.

but if you want all the roles' name you will need to iterate through the array or use `map` function.

```
user.roles.map(role => role.name)
```

Assuming that each role has property `name`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when i access roles with user.roles i am getting unresolved variable roles error.

Comment: it's also how you pass variable $users into vue.js, you need to pass the whole thing $users->toJson()

Comment: I am passing to vue component like this.

<usermanagement-component :users="{{ $users }}">{{ csrf_field() }}</usermanagement-component>

Comment: check on php side whether there are roles property, then you can use vue dev tools to inspect the value in vue

Comment: {{ user.roles.map(roles => roles.name) }}

This seems working but the name printing like this [ "Admin" ] i don't want braces and quotes in it.

Comment: sorry, I forgot .join(',' ) afterwards, you can customize your separator with the first parameter